# Filter Event (Strg+Z) on Pyqtgraph ParameterTree

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

In my current application I am using pyqtgraphs [ParameterTree](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/parametertree/index.html#) that inherently implements an undo function for its elements. However this interferes with my global undo-stack, therefore I would like to filter Strg+Z events.

ParameterTree inherits from QTreeWidget, therefore I tried some methods.
Firstly, I tried to install an Event Filter (but I am not sure, if I have done this right to be fair).

```
class FooterWidget(ParameterTree):
""" Class for meta-properties of the map footer. """

def __init__(self, main_gui, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent=parent)
    self.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
    ...
 def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    if isinstance(event, QKeyEvent):
        return(event.key() & Qt.Key_Control > 0)
    return False
```

This however  does not prevent the Ctrl+Z action from being done. Also when I am filtering any keyPresses (i.e. eventFilter returns True in any case), I still see some input visible. This makes me guess that in fact the actual event is propagated to the children of the parameter tree before the actual event filter.

Also a reimplementation of the `keyPressEvent` method did not help.
Is there any way to interfere with the local undo of the Parameter Tree or rather its items?

Comment: do not see that undo / redo is implemented in ParameterTree, only in the typo fields of Text (I have tested the code of http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/0.10.0/pyqtgraph-0.10.0-deb/pyqtgraph-0.10.0/examples/parametertree.py), so maybe I am wrong about it I ask you to provide a [mcve]

Comment: it in fact is not implemented into the ParameterTree, but rather into the QTextEdit / QLineEdit Widgets it uses. By subclassing the ParameterTree adequately I was able to work around those.